# How to know i have to put the design in frontend/default/default in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I just created custom module of Hello World. I put my view in frontend/default/default now i want to change this path in Admin panel.From where i can change this path ?

Can i put my view file in frontend/default/base ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template structure is frontend/[package]/[theme]

```
System -> configuration -> design
```

There you can change package and theme path.

So if you want your file in frontend/default/base and skin/default/base set `current package name` under package to `default` and set `templates`, `Skin`, `Layout`, `default` under themes to `base`.

P.s. if you mean frontend/base/default it's vice versa.

Comment: Thanks sir. Can i put my view file in frontend/default/base ?

Answer (score 1):

If you create a custom module that should be available independent of the theme, you should put your layout, template and static resources in `base/default` (under app/design/frontend or skin depending on the resource).
This will make it available for all the themes.
If you need a separate design for a theme, you can later copy those files in your theme folder and change only what you need.